# Margin difference in nested ListBox with DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, margin, datatemplate

I have a problem with my ListBox. I have written several DataTemplates which I use in a ListBox. Each one of these contains a grid and may contain a nested ListBox depending on the item.
My problem is: The height of these nested ListBoxes seem to be different to the root ListBox's height. Additionally it seems, that there is sometimes one pixel margin to the element above.

[image: NestedGrids]

Has someone encountered this problem, too and maybe solved it?

XAML-Code:

```
         <!-- Template for SubData-Items -->
         <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">

            <Grid x:Name="baseGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="999" Background="Violet">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col0, Path=Width}" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col1, Path=Width}" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=Row0, Path=Height}"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Bezeichnung}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" />
                <Line Grid.ColumnSpan="999" Stroke="Black" X1="0" X2="{Binding ElementName=baseGrid, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}" Y1="0" Y2="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Template for Items -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupDataTemplate">

            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="999" Background="Blue">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=Gantt, Path=GridRowHeight}" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid x:Name="baseGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="999">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col0, Path=Width}" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col1, Path=Width}" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=Row0, Path=Height}"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Bezeichnung}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" />

                </Grid>

                <Grid x:Name="expandedGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="999">

                    <ListBox x:Name="LBMaGruppen" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubdataObjects}"                                                                                
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,2,0"
                                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="false" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderThickness="0" />

                </Grid>

            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>

   <!-- Grid with ListBox -->
   <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row0" Height="34"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0" Width="25" />
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col1" Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="999" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource, Mode=OneWay}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupDataTemplate}"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto"               
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="true"
            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            FontSize="10" />

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, please update your question with the XAML so we can see how you are nesting everything.

Comment: In your sub items ListBox DataTemplate you are binding the RowHeight to the height of the Row in your "Grid with ListBox", I am fairly sure this won't work but more importantly I am not sure you want to be doing this! By setting the nested ListBox to the same size as the parent ListBox will only cause the parent Listbox to grow. What exactly are you trying to achieve? If it is changing the margin you can try using a negative value to remove the extra one pixel you are seeing.

Comment: What I try to achieve is that every line in the list has the same height, because it has to fit to a visual element right of it, which has vertical drawn lines. I also tried to give them a negative margin, but that will only cause the grid to make the above line invisible.

Comment: If you have nested datatemplates you should use ``HierarchicalDataTemplate`` instead of a regular ``DataTemplate``. Also, why are you setting the width and height of your rows and columns through binding? Why not use SharedSizeGroup, have you tried using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Margin="-2,0,0,0" and a Padding="-1" to your "LBMaGruppen" named ListBox.

```
<ListBox x:Name="LBMaGruppen" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubdataObjects}"                                                                                
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="-2,0,0,0" Padding="-1"
                                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="false" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderThickness="0" />
```

[image: Running with those modifications]

Also, the "root" element's height is binded to {Binding ElementName=Gantt, Path=GridRowHeight}, while the "sub" element's height to {Binding ElementName=Row0, Path=Height}, so this must cause the difference.

Comment: +1 and Bounty for an easy and clean solution. Did not think of setting the padding-property. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

qqbenq gave a very nice solution . Here is another way to do it.

the control templates of ListBox and ListBoxItem has padding inside their borders. Thankfully ListBoxItem border's padding can be control by a style like so:

```
    <Style
        TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter
            Property="Padding"
            Value="0" />
    </Style>
```

but unfortunately for the ListBox , you will have to override the default template with all of its details to change its internal border's hard-coded padding like this:

```
    <Style
        TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter
            Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate
                    TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <Border
                        x:Name="Bd"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Padding="0"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer
                            Focusable="false"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ItemsPresenter
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger
                            Property="IsEnabled"
                            Value="false">
                            <Setter
                                Property="Background"
                                TargetName="Bd"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger
                            Property="IsGrouping"
                            Value="true">
                            <Setter
                                Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                                Value="false" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

One last note : remove the Margin that you added inside your xaml.

Solution complete

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have auto height set on all your ListBox. You could try setting the height to a specific size. EDIT: I see you already have ScrollViewer settings. I think setting the height of the box to a specific size instead of auto will do what you want.

As to the padding between elements see the [ListBox.ItemContainerSyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.itemcontainerstyle%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which should allow you to set the margin between elements.

Comment: Setting the height to a specific value is no solution, because every item can have x subitems. I don't know that before. The scrollviewer must only appear in the root ListBox, because the lines in it have to fit to a visual element right to it. Playing around with the margin property didn't work either.